# Java - StackOverflow Error on recursive 2D boolean array method that shouldn't happen

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm working on a runnable java applet that has a fill feature much like the fill method in drawing programs such as Microsoft Paint.

This is how my filling method works:

1. The applet gets the color that the user clicked on using `.getRGB`
2. The applet creates a 2D boolean array of all the pixels in the window, with the value "true" if that pixel is the same color as the color clicked on or "false" if not. The point of this step is to keep the `.getRGB` method out of the recursive method to hopefully prevent this error.
3. The applet recursively searches the 2D array of booleans where the user clicked, recording each adjacent point that is "true" in an ArrayList. The method then changes each point it records to false and continues.
4. The applet paints every point stored in the `ArrayList` to a user selected color.

All of the above steps work PERFECTLY if the user clicks within a small area, where only a few thousand pixels or so have their color changed. If the user selects a large area however (such as about 360,000 / the size of the applet window), the applet gets to the recursive stage and then outputs this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:185)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)
 at paint.recursiveSearch(paint.java:190)  
 (continues for a few pages)
```

Here is my recursive code:

```
public void recursiveSearch(boolean [][] list, Point p){
    if(isValid(p)){
        if(list[(int)p.y][(int)p.x]){
            fillPoints.add(p);
            list[(int)p.y][(int)p.x] = false;

            recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x-1,p.y));//Checks to the left
            recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x,p.y-1));//Checks above
            recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x+1,p.y));//Checks to the right
            recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x,p.y+1));//Checks below
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can work around an error like this? I know that the loop will never go on forever, it just could take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Breadth First Search. You will have a queue of 'unprocessed' pixels. At first the queue consists of one pixel that the user clicked. Now while the queue is not empty, repeat the following step: take the next pixel from the queue, process it (paint to the color you need or whatever), and for each adjacent not visited pixel of the same color mark it as visited and add to the queue. If the area consists of 360,000 pixels, it should run in not time.

Comment: Thank you so much, using a queue I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the stack space for your Java process, for example:

```
java -Xss10m MyProgram
```

would give 10 megs to the thread stack.  I would advise against this, however, and consider writing an iterative version of your algorithm, especially if the number of recursive calls is dependent on some kind of user driven behavior.

EDIT:  For applets, I don't think you can specify `-X` flag values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're recursing at all. It would be one thing if you ever changed any points in `list` back to `true`, but apparently you don't. So why not just iterate?

As it is, you are potentially checking every point many times, when checking each point just once should be sufficient.

Another thought: If I'm not mistaken, your algorithm won't add *any* points to the `fillPoints` vector unless `list[0, 0] == true`. Is that the behavior you want?

---

**EDIT**: OK, now I have a better idea of what you're trying to do. I suggest you have a look at [this part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations) of the Wikipedia page on [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithms.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wikipedia link, the algorithms explained at that page helped me fix my error.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you check too much for each and every pixel.  I would suggest that you add a "level" parameter to your method which is initially 0 but incremented when calling recursively.   Then add an initial print statement showing the level of the current recursive call.

I think you will be surprised how deep you end in your code!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle arbitrary image sizes then you will have to rewrite this in a non-recursive fashion.  There is no other way to guarantee that your stack will be big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm makes sense on paper but as you've found out it doesn't scale well.

I doubt any graphics program would use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Recursing would be a good idea if you wanted to avoid checking all the pixels on the window. i would suggest changing the color of the selected pixel and checking recursively if there are any adjacent pixels that need to be changed too and going back if not, and so on. This way avoiding to have to check every single pixel in the window. (Imagine the case of a 800 x 800px window and you have to fill a 4x4px area. checking every single pixel would be overkill there.)

Answer (score 0):

From my quick look. I think you are going over areas many many times. You should update the the method to include what direction the call should not check back at. Like this:

```
public void recursiveSearch(boolean [][] list, Point p, String directionFrom){
    if(isValid(p)){
        if(list[(int)p.y][(int)p.x]){
            fillPoints.add(p);
            list[(int)p.y][(int)p.x] = false;
            //Add a check for which direction it came from and dont go that way.
            if (string.equals(right)){     
                 recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x,p.y-1),down);//Checks above
                 recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x+1,p.y),left);//Checks to the right
                 recursiveSearch(list, new Point(p.x,p.y+1),right);//Checks below
            }else if(string.equals(left){
              //... and so on
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't reduce the number of recursive calls to prevent the error. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

It *should* happen for a big image. You shouldn't use recursion. Maybe something like this:

```
LinkedList<Point> frontier = new ...
frontier.add(starting_point);

while(frontier is not empty)
    point = frontier.removeLast();
    point.state = (point.color == the_color)
    if(point.state==true)
       // expand frontier
       for(neighbor : neighbor_points)
           if(neighbor.visited==false)
               frontier.add(neighbor)
               neighbor.visited=true;
```